# calling jquery function from bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first post and I hope it will contain enough information to explain my problem.

As the title indicates, I'm struggling to get a jquery function to be called from a form within a popover.

I followed this article to create the popover:
http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/simple-technique-for-creating-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-popovers

This would create this code:

```
          $(".pop").each(function() {
              var $pElem= $(this);
              $pElem.popover(
                      {
                          html:true,
                          title: getPopTitle($pElem.attr("id")),
                          content: getPopContent($pElem.attr("id"))
                      }
              );
          });

          function getPopTitle(target) {
              return $("#" + target + "_content > div.popTitle").html();
          }

          function getPopContent(target) {
              return $("#" + target + "_content > div.popContent").html();
          }
```

The link to show the popover:

```
<a href="" style="" id="contact" class="pop"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Test</a>
```

and finally the div that render the popover:

```
<div id="contact_content">
     <div id="popTitle" class="popTitle">
          title sample
     </div>
     <div id="popContent" class="popContent">
          {% crispy quick_add %}
     </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to create the form manually for test within the div but it does not make a difference.

On submitting the form, I want to call a jquery function to initiate an ajax call.
This would look like that:

```
         $('.ajax_forms').on('submit',function(e){

              var form_id = $(this).attr('id');
              alert(form_id);
              var errors = 0;
              $('#'+form_id+' input[type=text]').each(function(){
                  if (!$(this).val()){
                      errors++;
                  }
              });
              if (errors > 0) {
                  ajax_alert('error','All fields are mandatory.');
                  return false;
              }
              e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/forms/'+form_id+'/',
                  data: $('#'+form_id).serialize(),
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                      ajax_alert('success','The data is saved.');
                  }
              });
              return false;
          });
```

When debugging, I added an alert to the submit call but no alert is shown.
What puzzles me is that if I simply display the form anywhere (using same crispy-forms tag) in the same page, I can submit data no problem.

I thought it was linked to the popover div being initialised as a 'display:none' but playing around and making it visible does not help.

To work around this problem, I'm showing/hiding div using jquery but I would prefer using popover.
I hope this is complete enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around, I understand that the form is added to the DOM but i thought that using on() was the way to handle this.
Anyway, the way i got it working is using this:

```
$('body').on('click','button.ajax_button',function(e){
   // your stuff here
});
```

The '.ajax_button' being the class I'm adding to the button on form's creation.

To retrieve the form's id, I use this:

```
var form_id = $(this).closest('form').attr("id");
```

Hope that helps.